# How to set end limits for csvread?

Tags: matlab, csv

Let's say I have data in a csv file
[1 2 3 4 5; 6 7 8 9 10;11 12 13 14 15]
Let's say I don't want the first or last columns or the first row in the data. How do I selectively draw that with csvread()?

I've tried tinkering around with setting boundaries, but csv seems to only allow a start point, from which it will draw to row/column infinity.

The ideal results would be somehow getting a matrix that is
[2,3,4;7,8,9;12,13,14]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [documentation](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/csvread.html) for csvread is accurate but confusing and somewhat non-standard for matlab. The basic syntax is:

```
a = csvread(filename)
```

And if you want to specify a range, you can use:

```
a = csvread(filename,R1,C1,[R1 C1 R2 C2])
```

where the R and C are the rows and columns of interest. The trick is that the row and column values are *zero-indexed*, which is unusual in matlab. Also note that if you are specifying a range for reading, the first components of the array argument are the same as the other arguments.

For example, consider a file "test.csv" that looks like:

```
1,2,3,4
1,2,3,4
1,2,3,4
1,2,3,4
```

The basic read operation is:

```
>> a = csvread('testcsv.csv')

a =

 1     2     3     4
 1     2     3     4
 1     2     3     4
 1     2     3     4
```

If you want to start reading at column 2, specify row *0* and column *1*:

```
>> a = csvread('testcsv.csv',0,1)

a =

 2     3     4
 2     3     4
 2     3     4
 2     3     4
```

And if you want to stop after column 3 while including all rows (i.e. up to row 4):

```
>> a = csvread('testcsv.csv',0,1,[0 1 3 2])

a =

 2     3
 2     3
 2     3
 2     3
```

In your specific case:

```
>> a = csvread('testcsv2.csv')

a =

 1     2     3     4     5
 6     7     8     9    10
11    12    13    14    15

>> a = csvread('testcsv2.csv',1,1,[1 1 2 3])

a =

 7     8     9
12    13    14
```

Answer (score 0):

Please refer to this documentation on *csvread* : 
https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/csvread.html

In the page, you can see various implementations of csvread() such as

```
M = csvread(filename,R1,C1)
```

where R1 is the row offset and C1 is the column offset. You can probably try your way around with this and solve your problem.

Comment: Well this comment didn't help at all. As I said, I've already tried what I can think of. It's not like I'm asking for some test answer or something, I'm just trying to find out how to better use a function.